# Firebase realtime database: writing new data is failing

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a bunch of data that needs to be updated in my realtime database but the `set` command ([as described here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)) isn't working. Here's my code, which I'm running with `babel-node scriptName.js`:

```js
var config = {
  //CONFIG
};
Firebase.initializeApp(config);

var dbRef = Firebase.database().ref();

getAllFirebaseDocs(dbRef);

async function getAllFirebaseDocs(dbRef, newSet) {
    var snapshot = await dbRef.once('value');
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var bookName = "FirebaseForDummies";
    var newData = {
        'prop1': 'string',
        'prop2': 0
    }
    Firebase.database().ref(bookName + "/edition/"+ 3).set(newData);    
}
```

I'm doing some other stuff which doesn't affect the write (hence reading all existing data). I'm specifically updating/augmenting existing data, so for example; the book `FirebaseForDummies` has 3 editions already. This means that the `editions` value in the database looks something like this:

```
0: {data}
1: {data}
2: {data}
```

I want to add a fourth, so I create the db reference with `FirebaseForDummmies/edition/3`. Then just like in the doc, I use `set` and pass it the `newData` object. This however fails silently; I don't get any error messages, and nothing changes in the realtime database console.

edit:
I tried these commands in a `babel-node` session in my console, and they worked. So there's something in my script that's making the `set()` function not work... not sure what it is, since I have other scripts that implement `set()` on existing data and they all work fine.

edit2:
I added a callback as follows:

```
Firebase.database().ref(bookName + "/edition/"+ 3).set(newData, function(error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log("written!");
        }
    });
```

Again, when I try it in a `babel-node` console it works fine (returning 'written!') but in my script, I don't get either the error or success console.log.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not to do a `process.exit()` at the end of the script. I didn't even think of it because I put it there simply to close the script when it was done, but apparently it was 'cutting off' the requests. I think I should make `await` work with the `set` requests so that this can all happen synchronously.